# xrandr --reflect: strange delay... sometimes

Tags: xrandr

This is about linux... Ubuntu 18.04 if it matters... Dell Inspiron laptop if it matters...

I'm finding that when I do "`xrandr --output eDP-1 --reflect xy`" it seems instantaneous, but when I then do "`xrandr --output eDP-1 --reflect normal`" (to put it back) there's a delay of something like three seconds, during which time the screen is black.  If the screen is already in normal mode, the latter command does not have a delay.  The same thing happens if I do this operation to my external monitor (HDMI-1) instead of to the laptop screen (eDP-1) except that the delay is slightly longer.  (Same thing with "`--rotate inverted`" followed by "`--rotate normal`".)

Why would this be, and is there some way to flip the screen without a long delay?